# I'm trying to pass a command line typed text file document as an argument but I am getting weird errors and I'm not sure why

Tags: bash

Here is what I have so far, it's not a lot but I'm just trying to get this going before I do other things to the text document.

```
#!/bin/bash 

filestats /home/linux.homework/filestats
file="$1"
filestats "$1"
echo "$file"
```

and the errors read as follows:

```
./filestats: line 2: filestats: command not found
./filestats: line 4: filestats: command not found
```

It will echo the file name test.txt and is working but I get those two errors in the output a well?

Comment: Tell as what `filestats` is.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `filestats`? Are you trying to create a variable `filestats`? Do you think it's a system command? Is it another script you have created?

Comment: Sorry, yea filestats is a script I am attempting to write. At commmand I want to type something like > ./filestats test.txt and have have text.txt be passed to the script to do various things to text.txt

Comment: What do you intend this line to do? `filestats /home/linux.homework/filestats` It looks like you are trying to call a script and passing itself as an argument.

Comment: @kmort To be honest that was an answer I found elsewhere. Basically I need to make a text file be passed ss an argument in the command line for example > ./filestats test.txt.  I find the line you are asking about somewhere as a solution to do this. I find it on Google somewhere. I am open to a different way to do this. The line works (I think) as the script on a whole can do other things to the txt file. So the file is getting there but I'm getting errors obviously from that line and filestats "$1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stat` or filestat?I don't think `UNIX` has filestat command. But it has `stat` command.

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# stat  /usr/bin/dcp.py 
  File: ‘/usr/bin/dcp.py’
  Size: 1029        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 4980944     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-02-23 00:29:55.016100319 +0330
Modify: 2012-03-29 11:53:55.801244337 +0430
Change: 2012-03-29 11:53:55.801244337 +0430
 Birth: -
```

In `FreeBSD` `-x` is mandatory for above output , but for `GNU\Linux` insn't mandatory.

Comment: Sorry, yea filestats is a script I am attempting to write. I know about stat as I am going to use that later for some information about a text file being passed to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it was shown to me to fix the problem. Simply get rid of the two problem lines. I found these lines else where as a way to pass a text document (ex. test.txt) into a my script called filestats (ex. > ./filestats test.txt) at the command line.

Here is what the new script is so far:

!/bin/bash

$#Reads user typed text document at the command line

file="$1"

$#Gets the size of the file in bytes

size=`stat -c %s "$file"`

echo "Filename:         $file"

echo "Filesize:         $size bytes"